# Only display cells with data extracted successfully with REGEXEXTRACT in a Google sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, regex

What I'm looking to do is paste a bunch of raw data to column B on sheet 1 then look for cells with specific criteria and move them to column B on sheet 2. I was able to use the REGEXEXTRACT formula with some success. I'm currently using the following formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(Raw!B1,"^[$].*")`

Sheet 1 is the sheet labeled "Raw" and I'm looking for any line that starts with the `$` symbol. When I use that formula and look at sheet 2 "Clean" on column B it's populating the cells starting with $ in the correct places but all other cells that don't meet the criteria are being filled with `#N/A` and `#VALUE!`.

My goal is to eliminate all `N/A` and `VALUE` cells and only display cells starting with `$`. Is this possible using this formula? Trying to clean up this data and having 6-10 lines of `N/A` between each line I need is somewhat annoying.

Comment: The contents of clean is the formula you copied down, not the value the formula is returning. It does have the value displayed (the value returned by the formula), but if the contents of raw are deleted, the formulas on clean will have no data to operate on and return all errors or blanks if you wrap the formula with iferror `=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Raw!B1,"^[$].*"),"")`.

Comment: Funny timing cause that exact formula you just posted is what I finally figured out myself after reading the links Swagrov below posted. I now have a bunch of blank cells between the cells containing the info I need. Any easy way to automatically eliminate the blank cells when I populate new data into the raw sheet? If not I suppose I can deal with it. Better than all the N/A spam.

Comment: @Joel the FILTER option will remove the blank spaces. Please see this screenshot and note the contents of C1 https://imgur.com/a/0uO7v28

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function.

You can filter with [`iferror`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304).

Essentially, `FILTER(B:B, NOT(ISERROR(B:B)))` (You may need to tweak this)

Comment: When the FILTER formula becomes available, it will be about that simple.